# ARM template - deploy a customScriptForLinux

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

In Azure, I have a centOS Linux VM running under a `resource group`.

I want to provision the unpartitioned/unformated harddisks by a script stored in Github Public repo.

But this template always fails with error below. The error says `cannot launch the script`, but is it really this reason? the github repo URL is viewable publicly.

Where can I find more debugging information and why this deployment fails?

```
{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"ResourceDeploymentFailure","message":"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.","details":[{"code":"VMExtensionProvisioningError","message":"VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'azureVmUtils'. Error message: \"Lanch script failed: [Errno 8] Exec format error\"."}]}
```

The ARM template file

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "variables": {
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "vmName": "az-prx-sc-we-vm-app-01",
        "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
        "scriptUrl": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Xixiao007/Azure-extension-scripts/master/vm-disk-utils-centos-0.1.sh"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), '/azureVmUtils')]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
            "location": "[variables('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "publisher": "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions",
                "type": "CustomScriptForLinux",
                "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
                "settings": {
                    "fileUris": [
                        "[variables('scriptUrl')]"
                    ],
                    "commandToExecute": "./vm-disk-utils-centos-0.1.sh"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CentOS you need to explicitly call sh, try changing:

```
"commandToExecute": "./vm-disk-utils-centos-0.1.sh"
```

to:

```
"commandToExecute": "sh vm-disk-utils-centos-0.1.sh"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed the cause for the error, though in my case, the script contains script code that only `bash` understands, so `bash xxx.sh` is my final solution.